# ECS: How does taskdefinition port mapping relate to service load balancer port?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I'm writing some cloudformation templates to bring up an ECS cluster with some docker containers in it. I don't fully understand how all the ports relate to eachother.

I have an `AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition`, which specifies a port mapping consisting of a `ContainerPort` - which I understand to be the port used by the process running in the container - and a `HostPort`, which I *think* is the port exposed on the EC2 instance.

Then I have an `AWS::ECS::Service`, which has a `LoadBalancers` section. This section contains `ContainerPort` again - but how does this relate to my task definition? Should this be the `ContainerPort` or the `HostPort` from before? If the latter, how does that work? Does AWS do a "reverse lookup" on the instances? E.g. "get me the host port of the container port XYZ"?

Answer (score 1):

> Should this be the ContainerPort or the HostPort from before?

One would logically assume the **HostPort**.  However the documentation indicates the answer is **ContainerPort**.  The reason for this design decision is likely because the HostPort can be dynamic when it's set to 0. You can't reliably specify it.

From http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecs-service-loadbalancers.html :

> ContainerPort
>   The port on the container to associate with the load balancer. This port must
>   correspond to a containerPort in the service's task definition. Your container 
>   instances must allow ingress traffic on the hostPort of the port mapping.

And,

> Does AWS do a "reverse lookup" on the instances?

That must be the case. We must infer that AWS is doing some magic behind the scenes to lookup HostPort.

Answer (score 0):

**but how does this relate to my task definition?**

Your task definition states which port your docker container will be listening, which is where the Load Balancer will route traffic to. That is the **ContainerPort**.

**Should this be the ContainerPort or the HostPort from before?**

Should be **ContainerPort**. This port is reachable from the Load Balancer to route incoming traffic to.

From http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecs-service-loadbalancers.html :

> ContainerPort
>
> The port number on the container to direct load balancer
>   traffic to. Your container instances must allow ingress traffic on
>   this port.

Comment: the quote from the CloudFormation docs has been updated (and as shown there it's questionable if it was correct before).